# Get records for multiple months in django query

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

How to filter objects for multiple months?

I tried this thing, but no luck

```
  Sample.objects.filter(date__year=2013, 
                        date__month__in=[2, 7, 9, 12])
```

Where as if i try for multiple ID's following will work

```
  Sample.objects.filter(id__in=[1,4,8])
```

How can i filter records for multiple months in django query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry there's no lookup for that (`__month` is already a lookup and you can't chain them), but you can do that with `Q` objects:

```
from django.db.models import Q

def month_in(months, field='date'):
    q = Q()
    for m in months:
       q |= Q(**{field + '__month': m})
    return q

Sample.objects.filter(month_in([2, 7, 9, 12]), date__year=2013)
```

Or maybe bring year in:

```
def month_in(year, months, field='date'):
    q = Q(**{field + '__year': year})
    for m in months:
       q |= Q(**{field + '__month': m})
    return q

Sample.objects.filter(month_in(2013, [2, 7, 9, 12]))
```

Then you can do things like

```
Sample.objects.filter(month_in(2013, [2, 7, 9, 12]) | month_in(2012, [9, 11]))
```